# Why can't my airflow webserver initialize properly?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, airflow, psycopg2

When I create a dummy DAG following the [Apache guide to airflow in Docker](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html) and run `docker-compose up`, the `webserver` container repeatedly fails and restarts with errors that look like this:

```
webserver_1  | [2021-07-26 18:44:42,905] {cli_action_loggers.py:105} WARNING - Failed to log action with (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "log" does not exist
webserver_1  | LINE 1: INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, event, execution_dat...
```

This error suggests to me that the webserver is unable to initialize the airflow db. This dummy DAG uses Airflow 2 and `CeleryExecutor`. I have run into the same issue following [this example](https://towardsdatascience.com/apache-airflow-and-postgresql-with-docker-and-docker-compose-5651766dfa96) using Airflow 2 and `LocalExecutor`, as well as my team's current setup, which uses Airflow 1 and `CeleryExecutor`.

What confuses me is that my teammates can run DAGs based on our docker-compose without issue (and presumably, others can run Apache's official quickstart successfully). So something is wrong with my machine (likely related to Postgres) that is somehow affecting my Docker images. What could cause this error across several different `docker-compose` airflow setups?

What I have tried so far:

- Restarting my computer
- Killing, removing, and rebuilding my Docker images
- Reinstalling Docker for Mac
- Uninstalling and reinstalling `libpq`, `postgres`, and `psycopg2` on my local machine (though in theory this shouldn't matter for the Docker environment?)

I am on Docker version 20.10.7, and docker-compose version 1.29.2.

Comment: What python version do you have? What macos version?

Comment: All of the Docker images I'm using run Python 3.7. The Mac python version is 2.7 (which I never use, since I develop locally using conda), and I also have conda environments with various Python versions, mostly 3.8. My mac OS is Catalina 10.15.7.

Comment: Just in case, did you do `docker-compose up airflow-init` before running `docker-compose up`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by completely cleaning my computer of Docker artifacts using `docker system prune`. I ran the following commands:

```
docker system prune --all
docker system prune --all --volumes
```

My previous attempts to clear Docker artifacts from my computer had been incomplete; killing and removing containers and uninstalling/reinstalling Docker was not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you did not  follow the "Before you begin" steps and increased memory needed for Docker https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#before-you-begin

Default settings for Docker for Mac, does not give you nearly enough memory for Docker to run Airflow.

Comment: Thanks! I did follow this step, though. I currently have memory set to 8GB. I probably would have had (more) problems if I hadn't-- it was set to 2GB by default.

Comment: Then I have no idea. Works for me. Do you happen to have M1 MacBook maybe?

Comment: I have an i7. And yeah, it's very mysterious. It seems to just work for everyone else. Hence the post on Stack Overflow XD